# Why does \num{} not work in situnitx's S columns?

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{SS}
        0.01    & \num{0.01} \\
        0.1     & \num{0.1} \\
        1       & \num{1} \\
        10      & \num{10} \\
        100     & \num{100} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:
[image]

Why does the left column display as desired, and the right not?

Secondly, I would like to add a range of numbers of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{rS}
        0.01        & \num{0.01} \\
        0.1         & \num{0.1} \\
        1           & \num{1} \\
        10          & \num{10} \\
        100         & \num{100} \\
        101--1000   & \numrange{101}{1000}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How would I do that typographically "correct"?

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove the use of LuaTeX-specific packages, which are not needed for the demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the first part of the question, the `S` column aligns numbers, and treats any other input as 'non-numerical'. So when parsing your second column, the `\num` macro is a 'non-numerical' value, and the cell content is typeset omitted from alignment. Simply don't use `\num` to indicate numbers within an `S` column.

On the second part of the question, ranges intermixed with decimal values are hard to align nicely: to be honest, such a table tends to suggest that there is something wrong with what you are attempting to present. That said, something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2,table-align-text-post = false]}
        0.01        \\
        0.1         \\
        1           \\
        10          \\
        100         \\
        101{--1000} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

will work in the case give. The idea here is to ignore the second part of the range for alignment purposes. I've also given a fixed size to the number as a whole, as this gives better alignment in general.

Comment: Wouldn't `{101--1000}` be a better choice in the last row? I.e. center it instead of aligning? Then the column will not be too tail heavy

Comment: @daleif It depends on the 'real' case (for example, how many ranges). I guess you should post this as an alternative answer (or I can edit it into mine).

Comment: That answer couldn't come more first hand. Thanks!