# Selectively use scientific notation in siunitx "S column"

Tags: tables, siunitx

My question is similar to [Scientific Notation Only For Large Numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111670/scientific-notation-only-for-large-numbers) and [Adjust the exponent to switch between notations using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45534/adjust-the-exponent-to-switch-between-notations-using-siunitx)

I have a table which, for the most part, has numbers between .001 and 100.  I'd like to use scientific notation for numbers outside that range.  I use an "S column", which doesn't seem compatible with the solutions linked to above.  If instead I use a regular column with the redefined \num command from above, I run into trouble aligning since I have post text (a \Star for statistical significance).

Below is an MWE that includes the code from above links.

How can I selectively use scientific notation and align my numbers correctly?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,siunitx}
    \sisetup{
scientific-notation=true,
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        round-mode              = places,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-pre    = ( [,
        table-space-text-post   = ) ] \Star 
        }
\protected\def\Star{$\text{*}$}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\ThresholdLow}{0.001}
\newcommand*{\ThresholdHigh}{100}

\renewcommand*{\num}[2][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=\ThresholdLow}{%
        \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=\ThresholdHigh}{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}%
        }{%
            \OldNum[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S}}
2006&\num{0.0004} &-0.0282\Star&0.0003 &-0.0015\\
     &(0.0361) &(0.0229)&(0.1285) &(0.0539)\\
2011&-0.0002 &-0.0315&0.0083 &0.0037\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know the details enough, but it's an idea: Before passing the number to `siunitx` compare it to your boundaries. If they are inside, just let them pass. If not, calculate the desired mantissa and the missing powers of 10. Pass the desired mantissa to `siunitx` and save the powers of 10 to a command `\missingpowers`. Invoke that command inside the tabular preamble after each row: `\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S@{\missingpowers\renewcommand{\missingpowers}{}}}}`.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach - I have no idea how to implement it, do you?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165155/scientific-notation-only-for-large-numbers-with-uncertainty/165165#165165

Comment: According to Joseph Wright at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35911/why-does-num-not-work-in-situnitxs-s-columns, "Simply don't use `\num` to indicate numbers within an `S` column."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fist solution** (doing it manually)

With the normal preferences, siunitx prints the numbers in the way, you type them in. `0.000001` is not printed in normal decimal mode, `1.234e5` is printed in the scientific mode. here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        tight-spacing           = true,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        round-mode              = places,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-pre    = (,
        table-space-text-post   = )\Star,
        table-align-text-pre    = false
        }
\protected\def\Star{$\text{*}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S}}
2006 & 4e-4 & -0.0282\Star & 3e-4 & -0.0015\\
     & (0.0361) & (0.0229) & (0.1285) & (0.0539)\\
2011 &-2e-4 &-0.0315 & 0.0083 & 0.0037\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And here the result:

[image: Tabluar, manual notation switching]

**Update: second solution** (doing it automatically)

Here is a version which checks automatically the numbers and format them correctly. First it checks, if the number is in the range between 0.001 and 100, or -0.001 and -100. Then `\pgfmathprintnumberto` is used to create a macro containing the number in a verbatim-like scientific form (e.g.`1.234e5`), which is interpreted with siunitx.

> **Update2:** Mirco had the right solution for the parenthesis spacing problem, and I edit my answer including his hint.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        tight-spacing           = true,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        round-mode              = places,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-post   = )\Star,
        input-symbols = (
        }
\protected\def\Star{$\text{*}$}

\def\mynum{}
\newcommand{\testnum}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{or(and(#1<100,#1>=0.001), and(#1>-100,#1<=-0.001))}%
\globaldefs=1\relax\ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{1}%
   {\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=3, verbatim}}% printing 12300
   {\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, sci, sci e, precision=3, verbatim}}% printing 1.23e4
\pgfmathprintnumberto{#1}{\mynum}\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S}}
2006 & {\testnum{0.0004}}\mynum & {\testnum{-0.0282}}\mynum\Star &
{\testnum{0.0003}}\mynum & {\testnum{-0.0015}}\mynum\\
     & {\testnum{0.0361}}(\mynum) & {\testnum{0.0229}}(\mynum) &
{\testnum{0.1285}}(\mynum) & {\testnum{0.0539}}(\mynum)\\
2011 & {\testnum{-0.0002}}\mynum & {\testnum{-0.0315}}\mynum &
{\testnum{0.0083}}\mynum & {\testnum{0.0037}}\mynum\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here the result:

[image: Tabular, automatic notation switching]

Comment: I fail to see how this helps though. The OP wants the conversion to be automatic afaik.

Comment: @Trefex: Then I missunderstood the question.

Comment: You can overcome the spacing problems with the parentheses by specifying the option `input-symbols = ()`. However, even with that issue taken care of, your answer does not seem to address the main concern of the OP, which was automatic switching between scientific and "normal" notation.

Comment: @Mirco:Thangs for your hint with `input-symbols = ()`!I will include this. And my second solution _does_ an automatic switching between scientific and "normal" notation, as you can see in the picture.

Comment: @MichaelP - Very nice solution. May I suggest you remove the "detect-mode" option, as removing it will (re)enable the use of typographically correct minus signs instead of dashes?

Comment: @Mirco: You are totally right, `detect-mode` is not needed! I have updated my answer.