# Scientific Notation Only For Large Numbers -- with uncertainty

Tags: siunitx, expl3

I've been using [Betohaku and Bruno Le Floch's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113145/28808) to [Scientific Notation Only For Large Numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111670/28808) to turn scientific notation of as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage[
    per-mode=reciprocal,
    scientific-notation=true,
    retain-explicit-plus,
    table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{~a},
    table-align-text-post=true,
    table-align-exponent,
    table-align-uncertainty,
    separate-uncertainty = true,
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\OldSI\SI%
\renewcommand*{\SI}[3][]{%
    \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)<=.001}{%
        \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(#2)>=1000}{%
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }{%
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\SI{83}{\mega\pascal} looks good, \SI{83(22)}{\mega\pascal} doesn't.
\end{document}
```

The problem is I have some values with uncertainties (as in the above MWE) and (of course) the comparison to a threshold value (hardcoded here) fails, so the code above gives:
[image: render of above .tex code]

Now siunitx can parse 83(22) into two parts, so it must be possible, but haing spent some time staring at siunitx.sty and the expl3 manual I'm none the wiser.

Clearly I can work around this by saying `[scientific-notation=false]` before the latter example, but the point of the code-based solution is consistency (for avoiding small exponents).

So is there simple way to achieve output like (83 ± 22) MPa from the input I have? Or a beginners guide to writing in expl3?

Comment: I'm working on a major `siunitx` update: flexibility in scientific notation definitely on my 'to do' list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I introduce a secondary parser `\parseuncertainty` which will separate out the mean value from the variation, and stuff them into two separate tokens.  Then,  your `\SI` command can compare against `\SImeanvalue` rather than `#2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[
    per-mode=reciprocal,
    scientific-notation=true,
    retain-explicit-plus,
    table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{~a},
    table-align-text-post=true,
    table-align-exponent,
    table-align-uncertainty,
    separate-uncertainty = true,
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new_eq:NN \fpcmpTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\let\OldSI\SI%
\renewcommand*{\SI}[3][]{%
    \parseuncertainty#2()\relax%                             NEW
    \fpcmpTF{abs(\SImeanvalue)<=.001}{%                      ALTERED
        \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
        \fpcmpTF{abs(\SImeanvalue)>=1000}{%                  ALTERED
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=true,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }{%
            \OldSI[scientific-notation=false,#1]{#2}{#3}%
        }%
    }%
}
\def\parseuncertainty#1(#2)#3\relax{%                        NEW
  \def\SImeanvalue{#1}\def\SIuncertainty{#2}}%               NEW
\begin{document}
\SI{83}{\mega\pascal} looks good, \SI{83(22)}{\mega\pascal} does too.\par
And \SI{12345(456)}{\mega\pascal} also.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not only almost instant but I learnt something about the use of `\def` as well! Double thanks.

Comment: @ChrisH While I've learned a lot about `\def` from many expert posts on this site, everything "cool" I learned about `\def` I learned from David Carlisle's esoteric solutions.  There is a lot you can do with `\def` as a parser, just by structuring the input stream accordingly.